# mcedit runs differently when it's linked

Tags: command-line

I've installed mcedit and in terminal I tried to set it up so that i can type `edit` instead of `mcedit` (because I found it easier to type).

A symlink works, a copy works also. But: `mcedit` invoked with `edit` will always show a start screen to chose the file although I actually entered it just normal like `edit test.cpp`.

How can I fix this?

Type prints this

```
$ type -a mcedit
```

`mcedit` is `/usr/bin/mcedit`

```
$ type -a edit
```

`edit` is `/usr/bin/edit`

Comment: Could you tell me the outputs of `type edit` and `type mcedit`, please?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by outputs and type? It doesn't print anything to the console I think, no error message or so.

Comment: If you open a terminal window and enter `type -a mcedit`, it should return one or more lines of text. Copy that (select with mouse, right-click, chose "copy") and [edit] your question, where you can paste it. Do the same for `type -a edit`, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no separate `mcedit` program.  Midnight Commander is a multiple-function executable that checks what name it is invoked under and behaves accordingly.

- `vi` or anything beginning `mce` brings it up as the Midnight Commander editor
- `view` anything beginning `mcv` brings it up as the Midnight Commander file viewer
- `diff` or anything beginning `mcd` brings it up as the Midnight Commander diff viewer
- Anything else but with the `-e`/`--edit` option brings it up as the Midnight Commander editor
- Anything else but with the `-v`/`--view` option brings it up as the Midnight Commander file viewer
- Anything else brings it up as Midnight Commander

Aside from a link named `vi`, you have a couple of other choices, including shell functions/aliases that expand to `mc --edit`, wrapper shell scripts, and using `mce` or `mced` as the command name.

Ubuntu used to have this, in the box, for you.  Debian Linux for about a decade had an `mcedit-debian` shell script (which `edit`/`editor` could link to) that did nothing but spawn `mcedit $@`.  This was so that the "alternatives" system could invoke the Midnight Commander editor under the command name `editor`.

Ironically, `edit` and `editor` have been *explicitly rejected* as ways to bring Midnight Commander up in editor mode, by its developers.  In 2010 `mcedit-debian` was replaced by a Debian-specific patch to Midnight Commander's argument processing to recognize `editor` for editor mode, just as it recognizes the less generic `vi` already, but this patch was rejected from Midnight Commander proper.

### Further reading

- [`mcedit-debian`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/mcedit-debian.1.html).  Ubuntu version 8 manual.
- [`mcedit-debian`](http://sources.debian.net/src/mc/1:4.6.1-6/debian/extra/mcedit-debian/).  *mc-1:4.6.1-6*.  Debian Source.
- [*wrong default to mc instead of mc -e*](https://www.midnight-commander.org/ticket/2638).  Midnight Commander ticket #2638.  2011-10-22.
- [*allow mcedit to startfrom 'editor' symlink*](https://www.midnight-commander.org/ticket/2799).  Midnight Commander ticket #2799.  2012-05-01.
- Yury V. Zaytsev (2010-08-09).  [*Re: Bug#592208: mc: Can't open files for edit (F4) with space in filenames*](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=592208#85).  Debian Bug #592208.
- Yury V. Zaytsev (2010-08-09).  [`patch/mc/3:4.8.3-10/alt_editor.patch`](http://sources.debian.net/patches/patch/mc/3:4.8.3-10/alt_editor.patch/).  Debian Patches.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really get it working with ln or cp, maybe mcedit checks argv[0]. I've solved it with a bash script which does "mcedit $*".